# Words that mean "walked in an annoyed manner"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I want to express that my character was walking away after her friend teased her a bit but she's trying to be serious. I don't want it to come off as she's angry, but just annoyed.

So I don't know if "stormed" or "stomped" would be a good match?

Comment: Yes they’re ;in addition to stump, pace and careen.

Comment: "stormed" or "stomped" would be considered angry responses. Maybe "she walked off" or "she walked away".

Comment: If you use stormed or stomped, it should be stormed off, or stomped off, or stomped away.

Comment: She could leave in a *huff*.  *Huff* is a word meaning upset, perhaps exhaling an audible sigh and whirling around.  It might be the word you want.

Answer (score 1):

Strutted off. It means to go away walking with attitude, stiffly.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/strut

Went off in a huff.  To 'go off in a fit of petty annoyance'.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/huff

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "left abruptly" would work.  Doesn't really say she's angry...just that she "had enough".

Comment: Please add references.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "marched off".
We can use "to march off" to mean that someone leaves abruptly, perhaps in an irritated way, without paying attention to the feelings of those around.

Comment: Can you talk a bit more why this is a suitable phrase to the question? We expect answers to be informative and explanatory.